# Subtotal doubled in cart after update

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, upgrade, grand-total

I recently updated my Magento store from 1.5.1 to 1.9.2.3 and noticed a weird error. When I add an item to my shoppingcart, the amount is being doubled:
[image]

This didn't happen before the update. I tried turning off my modules (and clearing my cache) but this didn't work. I've seen a lot of issues like this, but it seems like there aren't really any answers. Also a lot of people seem to experience this sporadically, but it happens to me all the time; it doesn't matter whether I'm logged in or not or something like that.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a solution:
https://keith.kg/magento-issue-subtotal-and-grand-total-prices-double-at-cart-checkout-stages

It's not a clear fix, but it works.

Comment: This URL is dead.